# Looking for a specific softcover book from the 90's, one in a series of 3 I think, had white cover about overpowered artifacts

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, product-identification, artifacts

I had the book in question at one time and lost it during a move. The front and back covers were glossy and white with not the greatest art. I think it was the 2nd in a series of 3, but I could never find the other 2.

It was a non official D&D supplement dealing with way over powered artifacts such as a dagger that would cause earthquakes when thrown into the ground, a single arrow that would turn into 100k arrows once shot, powerful armor, weapons,  rings, etc. It might have been a roll aid, or d20 system book.

Comment: From the 90s, so 2e, I'm guessing? Non-official makes me think 3rd edition, but if it was the 90s, that would be 2e, right? Is it possible it was from the early aughts? Just trying to pin that down so I can try and find the answer.

Comment: Was the product color or black and white? Was there an illustration on the cover? Did the text also include monsters?

Comment: It was black and white inside. 2e based. The cover was a plain white with a mix of treasure items in the middle colored. I'm  almost positive it had major artifacts on the title. Wish I could remember more. Found all my old books and such official d&d, but somehow lost the few non official secondary roll playing materials.

Comment: Don't want to put this is as an answer, because I'm definitely not confident in it, but so far the only thing that seems like it might be what you're looking for is Mayfair Games' Role Aids Fantastic Treasures 1 and 2. Is it possible that it's one of those?

Comment: No, sorry... Wasn't  a role aid product. I looked through all they had. Was maybe even from the early 2000. I can't seem to find anything on it at all on the net, was hoping someone else may have had this series of books. They are treasure based, overpowered items.

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't Supplement III: Eldritch Wizardry from OD&D?